# apollo vue useQuery or useLazyQuery hooks variable not recognising ref from page variable

Tags: vuejs3, vue-apollo

I have the following apollo query in setup. I want to pass the userType dynamically but ref of userType  is not recognising.

```
import getUserQuery from './getUserQuery.graphql';
import { useLazyQuery} from "@vue/apollo-composable";

const userType = ref(false);

const { load: loadUserQuery, onResult: onUserQueryDone } = useLazyQuery(
  getUserQuery,
  {data:{usrTpe: userType}} // variable
);


computed(()=>{
  if(store.state.userType){
     userType.value = store.state.userType 
     loadUserQuery()
  }
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

here we need to change primitive data type to non primitive  `false` to `{}` `const userType = ref({});`

```
import getUserQuery from 'getUserQuery.graphql';
import { useLazyQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

const userType = ref({}); /// instead null change {} object 

const { load: loadUserQuery, onResult: onUserQueryDone } = useLazyQuery(
  getUserQuery,
  userType // ref as variable 
);


watch(store.state, (currentVal) => {
   if (currentVal.userType) {
     userType.value = {data:{usrTpe: store.state.userType }}
     loadUserQuery()
   }
 })
```